# How remove some URL from a string in Python

Tags: string, python-2.7

I have a text and I want to remove the URL from it but I have problem.

```
document = re.sub('[^a-z]|http:\/\/\w+.\w+\/\w*', ' ', document)
```

Igot :
    document='rt @prettycolleges: university of phoenix http://t.co/d5wxsy332r good'

```
>> 'rt  prettycolleges  university of phoenix http     t co  d wxsy   r good'
```

but I want this result:`rt  prettycolleges  university of phoenix good`

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regexp like

'\s*http://.*?\s' (Find a string that have an url - http:// - and it ends with an space)

And because the sub function replaces what you're looking for, the code should be:

```
import re
document = 'rt @prettycolleges: university of phoenix http://t.co/d5wxsy332r good'

print re.sub(r'http:\\*/\\*/.*?\s', ' ', document) ## note the r (raw string)
>> 'rt @prettycolleges: university of phoenix good'
```

Comment: It is only work for the example I mentioned but for new example it is not work. document= 'rt @beasiswaindo: http:\/\/t.co\/uio40rq8hc beasiswa full s2 university of the w'

Comment: Thats because the url doesn't starts with http:// (you have escaped the slashes). I will edit my answer so can work on that case too